# Why does df -h show less disk space than board actually has?

Tags: partition, disk-usage, fdisk, yocto

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       4.3G  1.9G  2.2G  47% /
devtmpfs        980M     0  980M   0% /dev
tmpfs           981M     0  981M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           981M   33M  948M   4% /run
tmpfs           981M     0  981M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           981M     0  981M   0% /tmp
tmpfs           981M   16K  981M   1% /var/volatile
```

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 7.3 GiB, 7818182656 bytes, 15269888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier:

Device         Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1 16384    24575     8192    4M unknown
/dev/mmcblk1p2 24576    32767     8192    4M unknown
/dev/mmcblk1p3 32768    69859    37092 18.1M unknown
/dev/mmcblk1p4 81920 15269854 15187935  7.2G unknown
```

The image is built with yocto.
I would expect /dev/root to have a size of 7.2GB but it shows only 4.3GB.
Could anyone explain the reasons why `df -h` shows less disk space for /dev/root than board actually has (compared to `fdisk`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could anyone explain the reasons why `df -h` shows less disk space for `/dev/root` than board actually has (compared to `fdisk`)?

`4.3G` is the size of the filesystem mounted under `/`. `7.2G` is the size of `/dev/mmcblk1p4` which is a block device, a partition of `/dev/mmcblk1`(?).

Filesystems and block devices are different concepts (compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1446923/432690)). A filesystem usually exists inside some block device. It may be smaller than the block device; such situation is totally possible and most likely the case here.

Note nothing in your question really indicates the filesystem mounted under `/` exists directly or indirectly inside `/dev/mmcblk1p4`. `df` associates it with `/dev/root` which may be a symlink to `/dev/mmcblk1p4`; it may be something else though.

There may be an additional layer (or even layers) between `mmcblk1p4` and `/dev/root`, e.g. LVM.

Check `ls -l /dev/root`. If it shows you `root -> mmcblk1p4` then yes, the filesystem mounted under `/` lives directly in `/dev/mmcblk1p4` but its size is smaller. If `/dev/root` is something else then further investigation is required.

The rest of this answer assumes `/dev/root` is a symlink to `/dev/mmcblk1p4`.

There are tools to enlarge filesystems. First you need to know the filesystem type. Invoke `mount` and examine the relevant entry. It will look like this:

```
/dev/root on / type <type> …
```

`<type>` will tell you the filesystem type. Next:

1. Pick the right tool (`resize2fs` for ext2/ext3/ext4, `btrfs filesystem resize` for btrfs, …).
2. Read the manual.
3. Check if the tool supports enlarging a mounted filesystem. `btrfs filesystem resize` *requires* the filesystem to be mounted. `resize2fs` *allows* it to be mounted when enlarging. Tools specific to other types may require the filesystem to be unmounted; in this case you cannot resize what is mounted as `/`.
4. Enlarge the filesystem. Some tools can automatically check the size of the underlying block device and make the filesystem take all available space, if asked to. Check the manual for the right syntax.

I cannot give you one exact command to enlarge because I don't know your exact setup. Anyway, my answer to the explicit question you asked ("why does `df -h` show less disk space?") is: because `df` deals with filesystems while `fdisk` deals with block devices; filesystems and block devices are different concepts.